# Distance from maximum value for each distance

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I would like to calculate the distance to maximum value for each possible distance. As an example:

```
Row  Distance Value
1     1        2     --> 1 (Distance from Row 1)
2     2        3     --> 2 (Distance from Row 2)
3     3        3     --> 2 (Distance from Row 2)
4     4        1     --> 2 (Distance from Row 2)
5     5        5     --> 5 (Distance from Row 5)
6     6        1     --> 5 (Distance from Row 5)
```

Explanation: Row 6 has value of 5 because the first occurrence of maximum value between rows 1 through 6 was at distance 5.

I have tried to use some windows functions but cannot figure out how to put it together.

Sample data:

```
--drop table tmp_maxval;
create table tmp_maxval (dst number, val number);
insert into tmp_maxval values(1, 3);
insert into tmp_maxval values(2, 2);
insert into tmp_maxval values(3, 1);
insert into tmp_maxval values(4, 2);
insert into tmp_maxval values(5, 4);
insert into tmp_maxval values(6, 2);
insert into tmp_maxval values(7, 2);
insert into tmp_maxval values(8, 5);
insert into tmp_maxval values(9, 5);
insert into tmp_maxval values(10,1);
commit;
```

Functions I think can be useful in solving this:

```
select t.*, 
       max(val) over(order by dst), 
       case when val >= max(val) over(order by dst) then 1 else 0 end ,        
       case when row_number() over(partition by val order by dst) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as first_occurence
from 
  ap_risk.tmp_maxval t
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select dst, val, 
       max(case when flag is null then dst end) over (order by dst) 
         as first_occurrence
from   (
         select dst, val, 
                case when val <= max(val) over (order by dst 
                             rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
                then 1 end as flag
         from tmp_maxval
       )
order by dst
;

       DST        VAL FIRST_OCCURRENCE
---------- ---------- ----------------
         1          3                1
         2          2                1
         3          1                1
         4          2                1
         5          4                5
         6          2                5
         7          2                5
         8          5                8
         9          5                8
        10          1                8
```

Or, if you are on Oracle version 12.1 or higher, `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` can do quick work of this assignment:

```
select dst, val, first_occurrence
from   tmp_maxval t
match_recognize(
  order by dst
  measures a.dst as first_occurrence
  all rows per match
  pattern  (a x*)
  define   x as val <= a.val
)
order by dst
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the maximum value using a cumulative max:

```
select mv.*, max(mv.value) over (order by mv.distance) as max_value
from ap_risk.tmp_maxval mv;
```

I think this answers your question.  If you want the distance itself:

```
select mv.*,
       min(case when max_value = value then distance end) over (order by distance) as first_distance_at_max_value
from (select mv.*, max(mv.value) over (order by mv.distance) as max_value
      from ap_risk.tmp_maxval mv
     ) mv;
```

Comment: Clearly the OP wants the latter, not the former. And your solution (to the latter) is incorrect: since the condition val[ue] = max_val[ue] is true, in particular, for the first row, your query will output 1 for all rows of input. The OP posted CREATE TABLE and INSERT, so it is **your** obligation to test before you post. Definitely a downvote for that reason - no excuse for posting incorrect answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either `max()` or `min()` combined with `case when`:

```
select t.*, 
       min(case when val = mv then dst end) over (partition by mv order by dst) v1,
       max(case when val = mv then dst end) over (partition by mv order by dst) v2
  from (select t.*, max(val) over (order by dst) mv from tmp_maxval t) t 
  order by dst
```

Result:

```
       DST        VAL         MV         V1         V2
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3          3          1          1
         2          2          3          1          1
         3          1          3          1          1
         4          2          3          1          1
         5          4          4          5          5
         6          2          4          5          5
         7          2          4          5          5
         8          5          5          8          8
         9          5          5          8          9
        10          1          5          8          9
```

Explained logic and words *first occurence* suggest that you need `min()`, but third row in your example suggest `max()` ;-) In data which you provided you can observe difference in rows 9-10. Choose what you want.

Comment: The difference between my solution and yours is that in your approach, you must also partition by mv (in addition to ordering by dst) in the outer query. That's an additional sort, and now the ORDER BY clause causes a third sort - you can see it clearly on the Explain Plan, and the cost reflects it too: 4 for my query, 6 for yours (on the very small dataset). This is why I created the FLAG and used an analytic function with exactly the same analytic clause in the outer query as in the inner query. With that said, your query is certainly correct.